# Gradle Project Sync Failed Android Studio 3.0 (JDK 9.0.1)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, synchronization

I tried all solutions to fix it, but nothing has succeeded. (Turned gradle to "offline work", deleted .gradle files, invalidated and restarted. I also removed the jdk-android studio completely and installed again.)

Here is the problem's screenshot:
Android Studio 3.0 Gradle Sync Problem
[image]

Here is my java version
[image]

and [here](https://github.com/Hacklesss/logs/blob/master/idea.log) is the system/log file:

Comment: What is your System is it 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: 64 bit windows 10 home.

Comment: did you added jCenter() and google inyour project level build.gradle file

Comment: I think no. How can I do that? Can you be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

I think add build tools and sdk version 23 or 24
and if you select to use 23 build tools and sdk version, add dependency like this

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

Note:
Wherever its written 26, replace with 23, only if you choose to 23 build tools and sdk version
If there is still any problem you can ask.

Comment: I'm like beginner of these stuffs :) Can you explain more simple for me? (This and your other comment)

Comment: Ok, I will answer in detail

Answer (score 0):

You can open build.gradle file in Android studio, then change compileSdkVersion ,  buildToolsVersion dependencies like this

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
....
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

}

If you did not understood it, can you please share screen shots of your build.gradle file ?
Which is in left side of android studio, under Gradle Scripts -> build.gradle (Modual:app)

Comment: There is just "CompileSdkVersion" here. Other terms are not exist.
Github: https://github.com/Hacklesss/logs/blob/master/build.gradle1 and

SS: https://i.imgur.com/Si59ETN.png

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hackl.happybirthday"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'}
```

and click sync now (it will be automatically appear when you make changes in this file)

Comment: Try testCompile instead of testImplementation at this line

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
to
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

Comment: Nothing helped but thanks for your effort. I solved that issue with uninstall and reinstall 3 times. I dont know what is the problem but its succeeded anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
Take these easy steps as per developer.android.com
first add these lines on build.gradle file

buildscript {
    repositories {
            jcenter()
        // You need to add the following repository to download the
        // new plugin.
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}


after that
update Gradle manually, edit the URL in gradle-wrapper.properties to the following:
distributionUrl=\
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip


For your reference you can check the below link 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Android Studio completely and reinstall 3 times. In every step I clicked on Gradle Sync error messages and installed all missing files. 3rd time installation has succeeded with get rid of gradle sync problem with installing missing files correctly. I don't know how and why it has not been successful 1st and 2nd time installation. Anyway, it's done.

Note: Before that I have tried all of answers. Thanks a lot.

[Succeeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETJfX.png)